# Dropdown in AgGrid

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to implement a bootstrap-4 dropdown menu on AgGrid but when I keep the html dropdown the data table overlaps the dropdown. When I try to increase the z-index of the system, in doesnt work.

here is the html code

```
<div class="dropdown">
     <button class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
     </button>
     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
       <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Add loan</button>
       <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Add saving</button>
       <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Add currency</button>
       <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Add share</button>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Here is the AgGrid code

```
columnDefs={headerName: 'Action',
       field: 'actionElement',
       colId: 'params',
       cellStyle: {overflow: 'visible';},
       cellRendererFramework: DropDownComponent}
   ];
```

Comment: Please add the `HTML` code or paste a JSFiddle link

Comment: From which library does the DropDownComponent come from? ag-grid-angular, ngx-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap, ...? Post the whole code please of your component

Answer (score 1):

@Mariano is correct, you need to add a `cellEditorFramework` rather than a `cellRendererFramework` this allows agGrid to pass xy coords of the table cell on the page.

Make sure you set the column to be `editable`

and editors are activated on double click, you can change this with: `singleClickEdit = true` or globally on the grid options.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use an editor component. You are trying to change value of your cell.